# Q quote for select statement to prevent sql-injection

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can anyone give me an example as to how one can use "Q" Quote in a select statement (dynamic sql) inside a pl/sql block to prevent sql-injection?

Will highly appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: The quote syntax has *nothing* to do with preventing sql injection attacks. It merely substitutes one potential attack for a different one.

Comment: And what type of that substituted attack is?

Comment: Read Jon Heller's answer to the end - he gives a simple example.

Comment: Would you please advise me how can I put a q quote into this plsql script, I'm pretty new to pl/sql so please excuse me for that.                                                                                                            stmt2s(i) := 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO x FROM (SELECT MYTABLENAME FROM ALL_TABLES                      ';
    stmt2s(i+1) := '      WHERE TABLE_NAME = somevariable) WHERE ROWNUM =1;  This little script is part of a loop as one can see that I have stmst2s with an index "i" in the parenthesis. In this script I might have a quote in "MYTABLENAME" column in ALL_TABLES.

Comment: Read the docs, they have examples: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218

Answer (score 2):

The alternative quoting mechanism only offers a small amount of protection against SQL injection attacks.  It's not as safe and not as fast as bind variables.

Here's a simple SQL injection example:

```
declare
    v_sql_injection varchar2(100) := 'Not Jon';
    v_sql varchar2(32767);
    v_count number;
begin
    v_sql_injection := 'q''<'||v_sql_injection||'>''';
    v_sql := 'select count(*) from dual where ''Jon'' = '||v_sql_injection;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
    execute immediate v_sql into v_count;
end;
/
```

The converted string looks like this:

```
select count(*) from dual where 'Jon' = q'<Not Jon>'
```

This will prevent a simple attack:

```
select count(*) from dual where 'Jon' = q'<Not Jon' or 1=1>'
```

But it can still be defeated:

```
select count(*) from dual where 'Jon' = q'<Not Jon>' or 1=1 or '1'=q'<1>'
```

---

The `q` should be wrapped around each variable to (slightly) help prevent malicious input.  A slightly better approach would be to use [`DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_assert.htm#ARPLS65379).

**BUT**, that's still a poor way of protecting your system.  I can't stress enough how important it is to use bind variables.

Comment: Thanks for your example @Jon, I know bind variable offers more security but right now I have to just follow the pattern that has already been adopted so "Q" quote would do the job for me. And any example just showing how to use "Q" quote with a select statement (inside a pl/sql block) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I know people use q and then select statement, but don't know exactly how?

Comment: The code uses a `q` on line 6, to surround the input variable.

Comment: And also should q be put in front of all the select statements inside (lets say) a package something like                                                                   1)....  FOR rec IN (SELECT DISTINCT E_D FROM E_LANGUAGE ORDER BY E_D),                                                                                                    2) .....'INSERT INTO ' || TableName || ' COLUMNS(' || vColumns ||
            ') SELECT ' || vColumns || ' FROM ' || cTableName; continue in next comment.

Comment: ....'SELECT ' || vc2PK || ' FROM ' || cTableName || ' WHERE ' || cPK || ' NOT IN (SELECT ' || cPK || ' FROM ' || c2TableName || ')'; 4).... stmt              DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2S; (and then) stmst(1):='Select Something.NextVal into adno from dual; stmt(2):='tstr := '''||c2PK || '='' || TO_CHAR(:OLD.'|| C2pk ||'); I'M NEW TO ALL THIS SO ANY SUGGESTION WILL BEHIGHLY APPRECIATED.

Comment: By enlarge I'm trying to figure out where do I need to use "Q" quote is it to do with every select statement (whether has a where clause or not) or select statements with where clause only and /or select statements with a where clause which are part of a dynamic statement like stmt dbms_varchar2s or nested select statements with and without a where clause. Not pretty sure about all this.